# How to parse "the release of the want of the want of release"?

Tags: meaning, justin-torres, blackouts

In Justin Torres' *Blackouts*, which won the 2023 [National Book Award for Fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Book_Award_for_Fiction), the central character, Juan Gay, twice refers to "the release of the want of the want of release." In the first instance, the narrator reminds the dying Juan of a conversation they had had many years ago:

> "By the age of forty, you said, you'd been relieved of libido altogether."
>
> "And did you understand?"
>
> "Not then, no. The words I understood, sure, but not how you meant them."
>
> "The release of the want of the want of release. Though, as it turns out, libido was the last defense I had."
>
> <sub>Torres, Justin. *Blackouts.* New York: Farrar, Straus, 2023. p. 36.</sub>

Later, Juan asks the narrator about the latter's suicide attempt:

> "Well, what did you think the pills were for? A cure?"
>
> "No, Juan, I don't think I ever believed that. I guess I believed they were to annihilate some dark awareness. Make it easier to live in an uncomfortable world."
>
> "To be released of the want of the want of release."
>
> <sub>*ibid.*, p. 126.</sub>

Since **want** can mean both **desire** and **lack**, the expression *relase of the want of the want of release* is confusing to me. What does Juan mean? The phrase probably is intentionally ambiguous, but I would be grateful for its meaning(s) being unpacked, particularly as they relate to the novel as a whole.